# Understanding when to use theta for time complexity

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I (believe) I understand the definitions of Big-O, Big-Ω and Big-Θ; in that Big-O is the asymptotic upper bound, Big-Ω is the asymptotic lower bound and Big-Θ is the asymptotic tight bound. However, I keep getting confused with the usage of Θ in certain situations, such as in an insertion sort:

[image]

From what I understand this says that the insertion sort will:

1. Take at least linear time (it won't run any faster than linear time); according to Big-Ω.
2. Take at most `n^2` time (it won't take any longer than `n^2`); according to Big-O.

The confusion arises from my understanding of when to use Big-Θ. To do so, I was lead to believe that you can only use Big-Θ when the values of Big-O and Big-Ω are the same. If that's the case, why is insertion sort considered to be `Θ(n^2)` when the `Ω` and `O` values are different?

Comment: What is the source for these figures? Insertion sort should be `O(n^2)` in the general case, and only `Θ(n^2)` for in-place sorting of fixed arrays.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog bigocheatsheet.com

Comment: Hmm, I'd be wary of online "cheat sheets" like this, and stick to trusted sources like textbooks and lecture notes.

Comment: But that still doesn't make sense. You said yourself that insertion sort should be `Θ(n^2)` for in-place sorting, but how it that valid when `Ω(n)` is also true (when the array is already sorted), I thought `g(n)` had to be be equivalenet `Ω(g(n)) == O(g(n))` in order to say that `Θ(n^2)` is true?

Comment: "Ω(n) is also true (when the array is already sorted)" - depends on how the searching stage is done.

Comment: Right, but assuming that is the case, then how does it work?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can only use Big-Θ when there is no asymptotic gap between the upper bound and the lower bound on the running time of the algorithm:

In your example, insertion-sort takes at most O(n^2) time (in the worst-case) and it takes Ω(n) time (in the best-case). So, O(n^2) is the time upper bound of the algorithm, and Ω(n) is the lower-bound on the algorithm. Since these two are not the same you cannot use Big-Θ to describe the running time of the insertion-sort algorithm.

However, consider [Selection-Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) algorithm. Its worst-case running time is O(n^2), and its best-case running time is Ω(n^2). Therefore, since the upper bound and the lower bound are the same (asymptotically), you can say that the running time of the selection-sort algorithm is Θ(n^2).